# TTTAttributedLabel can detect links,but can't be pressed correctly

Tags: ios, tttattributedlabel

I am using TTTAttributedLabel to detect links, here is the code I init the label:

```
 - (TTTAttributedLabel *)getLinkLabelWithSize:(CGSize)size text:(NSString *)text{
    TTTAttributedLabel *linkLabel;
    linkLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width * 1.1, size.height)];
    linkLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    linkLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    linkLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    linkLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    linkLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
    linkLabel.delegate = self;
    linkLabel.text = text;

    return linkLabel;
}
```

I add the label to anther view(xxxView).

`CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:fon constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 40)];
  [returnView addSubview:[self getLinkLabelWithSize:size text:str]];`

[image]

And here is the label delegate method:

```
  #pragma mark - TTTAttributedLabelDelegate
  - (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

The problem is that I have to press the xxxView many times to open the link. It's there something wrong with my codes?

Can anyone helps me , please.

Comment: Did u ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

check if there is TapGesture for your cell content view,if yes, remove Gesture from the text message cell

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue, got really desperate when realised there is a fix in new released version